# Specialize template method return type by template string parameter

Tags: c++, c++-templates

For reasons that are purely cosmetic (i.e. to make the C++ API more similar to the same API for dynamically typed languages), I have several classes:

```
namespace O {
    class A {
    public:
        void foo() {
            std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    class B {
    public:
        void bar() {
            std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
        }
    };
};
```

and I would like to have another class `X`, with a method for each of the above classes that returns an existing instance, i.e.:

```
X x;
auto a = x.getObject<"A">();
a.foo();
auto b = x.getObject<"B">();
b.bar();
return 0;
```

not sure how to write and specialize the template `getObject`... I suspect that it will be overly complex compared to simply having the methods `A& getObjectA();` and `B& getObjectB();` and semantically almost the same... so maybe it looks like one of those "you are doing it wrong" things.

I tried something like this, but it has several errors:

```
class X {
public:
    template<const char *N, class T>
    T& getObject();
private:
    O::A a;
    O::B b;
};

template<>
O::A& X::getObject<"A", O::A>() {
    return a;
}

template<>
O::B& X::getObject<"B", O::B>() {
    return b;
}
```

I hope the question is enough of general interest.

Target language is any, preferably C++11 to maximize compatibility, but it would be nice to see how things improve adopting more recent C++ standards.

Comment: How about `x.getObject<A>()`?

Comment: Does it have to be `template<const char*>`? Why not just `template<class T> T getObject() { return T(); }` [example](https://godbolt.org/z/1bEv43qa9)

Comment: I'd like to avoid naming the type itself, because it has to be in a namespace (which here I called `O`)... so that would become `x.getObject<O::A>()`

Comment: `using A = O::A;` ? otherwise a lot of boilerplate code somewhere else, like `if ("A"), then O::A`

Comment: *a lot of boilerplate code* is acceptable :) I will anyways generate the C++ code for this wrapper API

Comment: at least make the template parameter a `char`, or if a single character is not sufficient use an enum, then you need to map that enum to the type. There is no magic that does that for you, you need to write the code

Comment: It can be done, but `getObject<"A">()` is not valid syntax until C++20, so forget C++11. Second, `x.getObject<"A">()` is not valid syntax even with C++20, and it has to be `x.template getObject<"A">()`, which is fairly ugly. Do you still want to do this?

Comment: With appropriate (macro) `STRING`, you might have `x.getObject<STRING("A")>()`.

Comment: @Jarod42, not really, you cannot explicitly call template member functions with that syntax. Same reason `std::tuple` uses `std::get<1>(t)` instead of `t.get<1>()`.

Comment: You probably tried it already, but with c++17, if you are stubborn, you can use enum as template param and auto as return type, and then impl it with constexpr if https://godbolt.org/z/x4ejM9Ydh

Comment: @FatihBAKIR: you can [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x81a119rE). (`template`  would be needed if `x` is a dependant name.)

Comment: @Jarod42, oops, you're right, guess I haven't been writing enough non-templates :(

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use an enum instead of a string. Strings are suspectible to typos, typically IDEs can help with typing enums, but not with typing arbitrary strings. Also strings as template parameter are only available since C++20. Then the function that returns the object can be as simple as:

```
enum type {A,B};

template <type T>
typename type_to_type<T>::type getObject() { return {}; }
```

Where `type_to_type` is a trait specialized for each type you want to map:

```
template <type T> struct type_to_type;
template <> struct type_to_type<A> { using type = O::A; };
template <> struct type_to_type<B> { using type = O::B; };
```

Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace O {
    class A {
    public:
        void foo() {
            std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    class B {
    public:
        void bar() {
            std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
        }
    };
};

enum type {A,B};

template <type T> struct type_to_type;
template <> struct type_to_type<A> { using type = O::A; };
template <> struct type_to_type<B> { using type = O::B; };

template <type T>
typename type_to_type<T>::type getObject() { return {}; }


int main() {
    auto a = getObject<A>();
    a.foo();
    auto b = getObject<B>();
    b.bar();
}
```

Even if you do use a string as argument, the basic idea will be the same. You need to provide the mapping between the parameter and the actual type to be used. And a trait like `type_to_type` specialized accordingly is an easy way to achieve that.

Comment: Between `enum` (non class) `type::A` which might be written indeed just `A`, the alias suggestion (`using A = O::A;`) seems shorter/cleaner.

Comment: @Jarod42 indeed. I have to admit that I don't completely understand OPs motivation. I interpreted question and comments as they do not want the caller to use `O` directly for some reason